# В чем минусы использования функции system() для удаления каталога?

Tags: c++

Программа под windows. Удобно вызвать

```
string a = "cmd /c rd /s /q c:\\temp\\1";

 system(a.c_str());
```

вместо того, чтобы писать самому функцию удаления каталога. Писать надо потому, что

```
   fs::remove_all
```

не удалит, если не убрать атрибуты файлов.
В чем минусы вызова таких системных команд cmd?

Comment: В запуске лишней оболочки...

Comment: cmd можно взять и подменить  - в папку с приложеним добавить:) Также нужно анализировать вывод - что бы возможные ошибки находить.